# Recursive Function for Server Control Collection of subitems

Tags: asp.net, custom-server-controls, servercontrols

I have control that has a list of items with subitems. I need to have a recursive function that collects the sub items.
e.g How do I collect and iterate this collection that has sub items?
is an ArrayList MenuItems the appropriate Type to use?

```
<myControl:Menu id="MyControl" runat="server">
    <mycontrol:MenuItem Text="Hellow World">
        <mycontrol:MenuItem Text="Hellow World">
             <mycontrol:MenuItem Text="Hellow World" />         
        </myControl:menuItem>
    </myControl:menuItem>
</myControl:Menu>
```

Here is the control:

```
  public class QuickControl: WebControl
  {
    private ArrayList MenuItems;

    [
    Category("Behavior"),
    Description("The contacts collection"),
    DesignerSerializationVisibility(
        DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content),
    Editor(typeof(MenuCollectionEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor)),
    PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerDefaultProperty)
    ]
    public ArrayList MenuItems
    {
        get
        {
            if (MenuList == null)
            {
                MenuList = new ArrayList();
            }
            return MenuList;
        }
    }


    // The contacts are rendered in an HTML table.
    protected override void RenderContents(
        HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        Table t = CreateContactsTable();
        if (t != null)
        {
            t.RenderControl(writer);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code even won't compile. You seem to know what you need so go and try to implement it. If even then you can't beat it, come back and ask a specific question please.